# Write a batch file to replace the number between first comma and second comma

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file to replace the number between first comma and second comma.

old.txt

```
time,in,out,all
06:00,1,0,1
06:15,12,0,1
06:30,6,1,8
```

new.txt

```
time,in,out,all
06:00,0,0,1
06:15,0,0,1
06:30,0,1,8
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this by writing some appropriate code. Note that StackOverflow is not a site for requesting code! You need to try something on your own and come back here when you are stuck, clearly describing the problem you are facing. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here! What do you want to replace the numbers with? always `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the actual file size, both number of fields and lines, something like this may suffice:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcFile=old.txt"
Set "DstFile=new.txt"
Set "RepChar=0"

Set "_="
(For /F "UseBackQ Tokens= 1,2* Delims=," %%A In (
    "%SrcFile%") Do If Not Defined _ (Echo=%%A,%%B,%%C&Set "_=T") Else (
    Echo=%%A,%RepChar%,%%C))>"%DstFile%"
```